# UrlRewriteFilter + Tomcat + simple forward rule produces 404

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

i have a simple problem:
what i want to do: redirect a request from `http://localhost:8080/mycontext/` to `http://localhost:8080/mycontext/somethingelse`

if i use the rule:

```
<from>^/$</from>
<to type="redirect">%{context-path}/somethingelse</to>
```

i get a 302 (Moved temporarily) HTTP response.
From documentation, what i want is `type="forward"`

but if i use the rule

```
<from>^/$</from>
<to type="forward">%{context-path}/somethingelse</to>
```

i get a 404 (Not found) HTTP response.

Why is this happending? Any ideas? It's such a simple use case :(

Answer (score 1):

problem solved.

Found in the documentation:

```
Note: In this case the "to" URL must be in the same context as UrlRewriteFilter.
```

i had to change the line `<to type="forward">/somethingelse</to>` since when using the `forward` type, you must NOT enter the context path.